# Calculating Radiation Pressure from plane waves on Boundary Surface

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

Suppose we have an incident Electromagnetic plane wave $E_I = E_{0I} e^{i(k_1 z - ωt)} \hat{x}$ and $B_I = \frac1{v_1} E_{0I}e^{i(k_1 z - ωt)} \hat{y}$ heading towards a surface $z=0$ between two mediums with $(n_1,μ_1)$ and $(n_2,μ_2)$. Then we have also a reflected plane wave $E_r$, $B_r$ and a refracted $E_T$,$B_T$ one, which are easy to find by implementing the boundary conditions.

I'm interesting in calculating the (time) average Radiation Pressure on the surface between the mediums. I know that force on a volume is calculated using Maxwell's tensor $$T_{ij}=  ε(Ε_i E_j -\frac12 δ_{ij}Ε^2)+ \frac1μ(Β_i B_j - \frac12 δ_{ij}B^2) $$

So the total force on a volume $V$ is:
$$F_i (V)= \int_{\partial V} T_{ij}n_j da - εμ \frac{d}{dt} \int_V S_i $$

Now $T_{ij}$ is the force parallel to the ith axis suffered by a surface normal to the jth axis per unit of area.I want to calculate the force on a surface,therefore I will only use the integral of $T_{ij}$.So am I right to write that the average pressure on the surface $z=0$ would be $$<P>= \frac{ <F_z (A)>} {A}= \frac1A <\int_{A} T_{zz} da >$$

(By $<.>$ i denote time average and A is just a finite surface at $z=0$). Is this correct, is there a nicer/more rigorous way of calculating the force on a surface?

Moreover how am I to calculate $F$ at $z=0$, since I know the fields left and right of $z=0$, not at $0$. Will I use $E= E_{0I}+E_{0R}+E_{0T}$, or calculate two forces, one for $z=0^+$ and one for $z=0^-$ and add them together?

Comment: I started off by writing what I thought was a simple answer. No, the answer is not simple and still a topic of contemporary research - see https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms5363